# Grails inheritance MongoDb collection per child class

Tags: mongodb, grails

In my Grails 2.3.8 application using mongoDb and inheritance, I have this base domain class:

```
class Record {
long batchID
static mapping = { tablePerHierarchy false }
}
```

and this child class:

```
class IndividualRecord extends Record {
    String uniqueId
    String firstName
    String middleName

    static mapping = {
        collection "individualRecords"
        database "twcdb"
    }

    static constraints = {
        firstName(nullable: true)
        middleName(nullable: true)
    }
```

}

The problem is that I want my child classes to be mapped to their own mongoDb collections but even with the configuration above, my IndividualRecord objects are being saved in a collection called "record" which is the name of the base class. What am I missing? On thing interesting is that this behaviour doesn't seem to change whether I remove this code from my child class or not:

```
static mapping = {
        collection "individualRecords"
        database "twcdb"
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The MongoDB plugin currently doesn't support the `tablePerHierarchy` setting for inheritance  for a couple or reasons:

a) MongoDB doesn't support joins, so to get all the data you would need multiple queries which would perform poorly

b) Even if it did support `tablePerHierarchy` MongoDB doesn't have tables it wouldn't be called that.

Comment: Thank for the response. I just thought it might help search times if my child records are separated on a per collection basis and that way I could have several medium sized collections as opposed to one large collection.

Answer (score 1):

Use aggregation instead of inheritance:

```
class IndividualRecord {

 Record base

 static embedded = [ 'base' ]

}
```

Comment: Will this lead to separate collections per child class?

Comment: yes, as there will be no parent or child classes >)

Answer (score 0):

Use AbstractPersistanceListner to handle the persistance events. Here is the code example for that And register this listner in bootstrap.groovy. for full code http://jagadeeshmanne.blogspot.in/2016/06/custom-persistence-listener-in-mongodb.html. You can assign the property value by checking entityObject.class.name.equals(IndividualRecord.class.name) then assign batchID value

```
import org.grails.datastore.mapping.core.Datastore
import org.grails.datastore.mapping.engine.event.AbstractPersistenceEvent
import org.grails.datastore.mapping.engine.event.AbstractPersistenceEventListener
import org.grails.datastore.mapping.engine.event.PreDeleteEvent
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationEvent

import org.grails.datastore.mapping.engine.event.EventType

class MongoPersistanceListener extends AbstractPersistenceEventListener  {

    def springSecurityService

    public MongoPersistanceListener(final Datastore datastore, def springSecurityService) {
        super(datastore)
        this.springSecurityService = springSecurityService
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPersistenceEvent(final AbstractPersistenceEvent event) {
        def entity = event.entityObject
        switch(event.eventType) {
            case EventType.PreInsert:
                initDefaults(entity)
                break
            case EventType.PostInsert:
                break
            case EventType.PreUpdate:
                def currentUser = springSecurityService.getCurrentUser()
                event.entityObject.updatedBy = currentUser ? currentUser.id : 0;
                event.entityObject.updatedOn = new Date();
                break;
            case EventType.PostUpdate:
                break;
            case PreDeleteEvent:
                break;
            case EventType.PostDelete:
                break;
            case EventType.PreLoad:
                break;
            case EventType.PostLoad:
                break;
            case EventType.Validation:
                initDefaults(entity)
                break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean supportsEventType(Class<!--? extends ApplicationEvent--> eventType) {
        return true
    }

    void initDefaults(entity) {
        def currentUser = springSecurityService.getCurrentUser()
        if (entity.createdBy == null) {
            entity.createdBy = currentUser? currentUser.id : 0;
        }
        if (entity.createdOn == null) {
            entity.createdOn = new Date();
        }
        if (entity.updatedBy == null) {
            entity.updatedBy = currentUser? currentUser.id : 0;
        }
        if (entity.updatedOn == null) {
            entity.updatedOn = new Date();
        }
    }
}
```